# Can AWS device farm be used for a load test with larger number (around 1000) of the same device instances at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I have a service deployed in AWS ECS that will be used by android devices to poll data (simple explanation of the service). I am required to test the performance of the service when a larger number of mobile devices are polling at the same time.

I have checked AWS device farm for achieving this scenario and I read the documentation and I am still doubtful of this. AWS device farm provides a platform of multiple devices for your automation and testing purposes but does this support this type of scenario? What I simply want is to use the same android device but a larger number of instances (e.g. - 1000 instances) polling at the same time to the service.

Can this be achieved using AWS device farm or any other ideal suggesting approaches for this?

PS - I know this can be achieved without actually using mobile devices and performing a load test using such a tool like K6. having several other reasons to evaluate this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this load-testing use case isn’t supported on Device Farm, as our platform only uses real physical mobile devices. We would recommend to use traditional API-based load-testing in combination with device testing on a single device so that you can see what the experience on that device looks like when there is load being placed on the server. For example, if you use a tool like K6, you can run a test using Device Farm’s custom environment mode (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments-extending.html) on a single device with a test spec file that load tests your API for you, then runs a basic smoke test on the app while the app’s server is under load.